# Adding digits to a variable using tkinter buttons in python

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am trying to build a GUI Based Calculator, nothing fancy, just with basic operators (add, subtract, multiply and divide). However I am trying to use buttons to input the numbers to be added/subtracted, like a real calculator. I am using a variable, `num1`, to store the first number, and `num2` to store the second number, so for example,
`num1 + num2 = result`

However I don't know how to say, if button 1 is pressed twice, make `num1` contain the value 11?

If I want to add 12 to 43, I need a way of setting `num1` to 12, by pressing button1, then button2. Then specify my operator by pressing the add button, then pressing button4 and button3 to set `num2` to 43.

Here is my Code (Note: I haven't yet finished the buttons labelled button1 - button0):

```
from tkinter import *

operator = ''
current_problem = ''

# Functions to change text in workspace
def add():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '+'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'A'
def subtract():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '-'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'S'
def divide():
    global current_problem
    current_problem + current_problem + '÷'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'D'
def multiply():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '×'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'M'
def num1():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '1'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)

# Create the main Tkinter Window
window = Tk()
window.title('Calculator')

# Add an empty Label for the workspace, place it in grid
workspace = Label(window, width = 25, height = 1, text = '')
workspace.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

add_button = Button(window, text = '+', width = 2, command = add)
add_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
subtract_button = Button(window, text = '-', width = 2, command = subtract)
subtract_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
divide_button = Button(window, text = '÷', width = 2, command = divide)
divide_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
multiply_button = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
multiply_button.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

button1 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button1.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button2 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button2.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button3 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button3.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button4 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button5 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button5.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button6 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button6.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button7 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button7.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button8 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button8.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button9 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button9.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
button0 = Button(window, text = '×', width = 2, command = multiply)
button0.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your problem is or what you already have. Please consider creating a [mcve].

Comment: @ChristianDean I have added an example

Comment: I understand your example @DaneBaird, but could you add an [mcve] to your question. What code do you already have?

Comment: The example you've provided is not minimal (The smallest amount of code needed to replicate the problem), complete (I fail to see any number buttons on it) nor verifiable (There don't seem to be any errors in it. Can you please provide us with an example that actually lets us see the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to finish your whole program for you, but the following shows how to add digits to a variable using buttons as well as overall a better way to layout your GUI.

To make it easy to add digits to the `workspace` label, I created a `StringVar` and associated it the `Label` by using `textvariable=` option when creating it. To actually add the digits, a function was added named `add_digit()` and a `lambda` function that makes a call to it is created and used as the `command=` callback function on each digit `Button`.

A good way to layout complex GUI widgets when using tkinter is to create nested `Frame`s and put groups of them in one. This allow to position the whole group via their containing `Frame`. It also allows you to arrange things in the container without concern for exactly the other widgets are being placed.

```
from tkinter import *

operator = ''
current_problem = ''

# Function to change text in workspace
def append_to_workspace(item):
    """ Add item to workspace StringVar. """
    if not isinstance(item, str):
        item = str(item)
    ws_var.set(ws_var.get() + item)


# Functions to change text in workspace
def add():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '+'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'A'

def subtract():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '-'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'S'

def divide():
    global current_problem
    current_problem + current_problem + '÷'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'D'

def multiply():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '×'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)
    operator = 'M'

def num1():
    global current_problem
    current_problem = current_problem + '1'
    workspace.config(text = current_problem)

# Create the main Tkinter Window
window = Tk()
window.title('Calculator')

# Add an empty Label for the workspace, place it in grid
ws_var = StringVar(value='')
workspace = Label(window, width=25, height=1, textvariable=ws_var)
workspace.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Operator keypad
operators = Frame(window)

add_button = Button(operators, text='+', width=2, command=add)
add_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
subtract_button = Button(operators, text='-', width=2, command=subtract)
subtract_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
divide_button = Button(operators, text='÷', width=2, command=divide)
divide_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
multiply_button = Button(operators, text='×', width=2, command=multiply)
multiply_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

operators.grid(row=1)

# Numeric keypad
numbers = Frame(window)

button7 = Button(numbers, text='7', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(7))
button7.grid(row=0, column=0)
button8 = Button(numbers, text='8', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(8))
button8.grid(row=0, column=1)
button9 = Button(numbers, text='9', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(9))
button9.grid(row=0, column=2)

button4 = Button(numbers, text='4', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(4))
button4.grid(row=1, column=0)
button5 = Button(numbers, text='5', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(5))
button5.grid(row=1, column=1)
button6 = Button(numbers, text='6', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(6))
button6.grid(row=1, column=2)

button1 = Button(numbers, text='1', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(1))
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
button2 = Button(numbers, text='2', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(2))
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)
button3 = Button(numbers, text='3', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(3))
button3.grid(row=2, column=2)

button0 = Button(numbers, text='0', width=2, command=lambda: append_to_workspace(0))
button0.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

numbers.grid(row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like running on my system:

[image: screenshot of application running]